# execute Bash command from IPython

Tags: bash, ipython

I want to source my bash environment when executing a bash command from IPython using the `!` operator, thus allowing me access to my defined bash functions:

```
In[2]: !<my_fancy_bash_function> <function_argument>
```

currently IPython is sourcing `sh` rather than `bash`:

```
In[3]: !declare -F
sh: 1: declare: not found
```

How to source `bash` and set my environment settings from IPython?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Fernando Perez, creator of IPython, [suggests this](https://twitter.com/fperez_org/status/352181845980479488):

```
In [1]: %%bash
. ~/.bashrc
<my_fancy_bash_function> <function_argument>
```

This works on the current stable version (0.13.2). He admits that's a bit clunky, and welcomes [pull requests](https://github.com/ipython/ipython). . .

Answer (score 29):

If the `!` implementation uses [`IPython.utils._process_posix.system`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py) under the hood, then it is going to use whatever `which sh` returns as the processing shell.  This could be a true implementation of Bourne shell - it is likely Bash in some compatibility mode on many Linuxes.  On my MacBook Pro it looks like it is a raw Bash shell:

```
In [12]: !declare -F

In [13]: !echo $BASH
/bin/sh

In [14]: !echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.48(1)-release

In [15]: import os

In [16]: os.environ['SHELL']
Out[16]: '/bin/zsh'
```

I was hoping that it would use the `$SHELL` environment variable but it does not seem to today.  You can probably branch the github repo, modify the `ProcessHandler.sh` property implementation to peek into `os.environ['SHELL']` and use this if it is set instead of calling `pexpect.which('sh')`.  Then issue a pull request.

Comment: great reply, thanks. What, in your view, would be a good way of setting up the environment in the spawned process which is coming from  the `!` implementation (linked to in your answer)? Doing a quick 'ghetto' test of symlinking /bin/bash to /bin/sh and issuing `! source ~/.bashrc && declare -F` yields nothing, whereas `! env && declare -F` correctly prints out my declared variables, but the bash functions are still not accessible...any ideas what is going on there?

Comment: On recent version you can use the %%bash cell magic to execute multiline bash.

Comment: Discovered something quite amazing... you can use the simple `bash` variable expansion tricks to expand a variable declared in `python`! For example `extension=".txt"` followed by `!ls *"$extension"` prints all `.txt` files!