# IPython Notebook: %run magic on non-python file types

Tags: python, ipython

From in the notebook, it's easy to run an external python module with `%run`.  For example, if I wanted to run foo.py:

```
 %run foo
```

But how does one run a file not ending in `.py`?  For example, if I had a bash script, `bar`.  When I try:

```
 %run bar
 ERROR: File `u'$bar.py'` not found.
```

A while back, someone showed me how to pass the filename so that `%run` doesn't append the .py suffix, but I can't dig it up!

Thanks

### Some Context for why I want to do it this way

Thanks for the comments.  To address why I'd like to do something like this, we are distributing an assignment in the IPython notebook for students in an intro programming class, and want them to use `nbconvert` to submit it as an HTML file.  Many of them use windows, and are using Canopy as their Python distribution.  To "open a terminal, cd to the working directory and running nbconvert" would be difficult, especially if nbconvert is not in their environmental variables.  It would be much easier on us to just have a one-liner that they can run from within the notebook environment.

Comment: why would you want to do this? ... I dont have an answer to your question, but I have a hard time imagining a scenario where this is the right thing to do ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [execute Bash command from IPython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927142/execute-bash-command-from-ipython)

Comment: Joran, I edited my answer to explain why we think it's a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creator of ipython [suggests](https://twitter.com/fperez_org/status/352181845980479488) this:

```
%%bash 
. ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the %%bash magic worked fine.  Sorry I didn't catch this.

```
%%bash 
ipython nbconvert --to html worldmap_notebook.ipynb
```